# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css, webpack-dev-server

I am creating a react app without using **npx create-react-app**, i am using webpack, and trying to use the tailwind CSS, with it.
But getting error.

How should I do confugration the to the react app so that I can use tailwind in this ?

error:

```
ERROR in ./index.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @tailwind base;
| @tailwind components;
| @tailwind utilities;
 @ ./index.js 4:0-21

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 43 ms
```

Index.css in react app:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

index.js of react app

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./src/App";
import "./index.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

my webpack file:

```
const path = require("path");

/*We are basically telling webpack to take index.js from entry. Then check for all file extensions in resolve. 
After that apply all the rules in module.rules and produce the output and place it in main.js in the public folder.*/

module.exports = {
  /** "mode"
   * the environment - development, production, none. tells webpack
   * to use its built-in optimizations accordingly. default is production
   */
  mode: "development",
  /** "entry"
   * the entry point
   */
  entry: "./index.js",
  output: {
    /** "path"
     * the folder path of the output file
     */
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    /** "filename"
     * the name of the output file
     */
    filename: "main.js",
  },
  /** "target"
   * setting "node" as target app (server side), and setting it as "web" is
   * for browser (client side). Default is "web"
   */
  target: "web",
  devServer: {
    /** "port"
     * port of dev server
     */
    port: "3000",
    /** "static"
     * This property tells Webpack what static file it should serve
     */
    static: ["./public"],
    /** "open"
     * opens the browser after server is successfully started
     */
    open: true,
    /** "hot"
     * enabling and disabling HMR. takes "true", "false" and "only".
     * "only" is used if enable Hot Module Replacement without page
     * refresh as a fallback in case of build failures
     */
    hot: true,
    /** "liveReload"
     * disable live reload on the browser. "hot" must be set to false for this to work
     */
    liveReload: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    /** "extensions"
     * If multiple files share the same name but have different extensions, webpack will
     * resolve the one with the extension listed first in the array and skip the rest.
     * This is what enables users to leave off the extension when importing
     */
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json"],
  },
  module: {
    /** "rules"
     * This says - "Hey webpack compiler, when you come across a path that resolves to a '.js or .jsx'
     * file inside of a require()/import statement, use the babel-loader to transform it before you
     * add it to the bundle. And in this process, kindly make sure to exclude node_modules folder from
     * being searched"
     */
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js|\.jsx$/, //kind of file extension this rule should look for and apply in test
        exclude: /node_modules/, //folder to be excluded
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader", //loader which we are going to use
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
          },
        },
      },

      {
        test: /\.(css|sass)$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader", "raw-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

My package json

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server .",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Ravi_Bro",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.7",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.7",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "eslint": "^8.30.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "json-server": "^0.17.1",
    "postcss": "^8.4.20",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.20.7",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.20.4",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "node-sass": "^8.0.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "path-to-regexp": "^6.2.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-query": "^3.39.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Verify you have done these first two steps : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation

Comment: Yes, you can verify using the package.json also

Answer (score 0):

Can you also provide the tailwind.config.js?

Also there are postcss library installed in package.json, the doc says there’re no support with postcss library in create react app. Please check here.

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app

Comment: /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
  prefix: "tw-",
};

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `postcss` loader (which will pick up the config with tailwind) to the `use` chain of loaders in `module.rules` with `test: /\.(css|sass)$/i`.

Comment: yes add 
{
        test: /\.(css|sass)$/i,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader",
          "raw-loader",
          "postcss-loader",
        ],
      },

But still the error

Comment: Do you have the config for `postcss-loader` set up?

Comment: NO 
I have setup the.   postcss.CONFIG.JS
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    "postcss-import": {},
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

Comment: POSTCSS.Config.js
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");
module.exports = {
  plugins: ["postcss-preset-env", tailwindcss],
};

No PostCss-loader setup